# Can the CakePHP form helper be coerced to include a custom attribute?

Tags: forms, cakephp

What I need to do is create a form something like this:

```
<form method="post" promptpermission="email" action="blahblah">
```

(Note the **promptpermission** attribute.)

Is there any way I can do this without straying to far from the helper?

```
<?php echo $form->create(); ?>
```

Since it's only one form, I'm loath to go mod very much. Is there a quick and easy way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty sure the [second argument](http://api.cakephp.org/view_source/form-helper/#line-89) is an options array:

```
<?php echo $form->create(null, array('promptpermission' => 'email')); ?>
```

Do note that custom attributes are not valid (X)HTML.

Comment: Yeah and it makes my skin crawl using them. But it's for facebook and they'll be stripped out... I'll give this a go, thanks.

Comment: I'm a little ashamed that it was that simple, but I'm still very grateful. Thanks Paolo!